# How to change the disabled attribute of the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I don't know how to change the disabled attribute of the button during the react test through the react-test-library && jest
Button set is disabled when user permissions are not allowed

```
const mockFindServer = jest.fn();
const mockAddServer = jest.fn();
const mockHandleClose = jest.fn();

const { getAllByText } = render(
  <FindServerModal
    isOpen
    isEmpty={false}
    isFailed={false}
    serverCandidates={[
      { name: 'TEST1', syncIpAddress: '1.1.1.1' },
      { name: 'TEST2', syncIpAddress: '1.1.1.2' },
    ]}
    findServer={mockFindServer}
    addServer={mockAddServer}
    onClose={mockHandleClose}
  />,
);

it('test button', () => {
  const buttons = getAllByTest('Add');  # two disabled buttons

  buttons.map(btn => {
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
    fireEvent.click(btn);
  })

  expect(mockAddServer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);  # failed
})
```

Comment: How is the button getting disabled in actual application, is it based on some props. Or how the button is getting enabled or disabled. Can you explain little more on this.Then it will be easier to help

Comment: based on some props(user's auth level)

Comment: so you can have two test case isn't one for enabled and one for disabled and you can pass the props accordingly

Comment: Can't change it in the jest-dom? like setAttribute function

Comment: If you set it that way, it defeats the whole purpose of testing.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case button is disabled because camera is not available.But I want to test, what if camera was available?